# Qt : Widgets must be created in the GUI thread

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5, qwidget

I am facing this issue which crashes my Qt-based app at seemingly random times after running for a while (a few minutes).

```
ASSERT failure in QWidget: "Widgets must be created in the GUI thread.", file kernel\qwidget.cpp, line 1145
```

Where to even start to debug this ? Even trying to isolate new pieces of code that I recently added to see if this issue persists has proven inconclusive.

I have code to generate a display using a .ui file, which I also manually extend in the display class with things like this :

```
/* main widget */
QMainWindow* tmpQMainWindow = new QMainWindow();
ui.setupUi(tmpQMainWindow);
m_pDisplayWidget = tmpQMainWindow->centralWidget();

m_staticHandler.setPortGraphics(m_pPortGraphics);

...

/* Button for sensor input */
guiInfo.inputButton = new QPushButton(ui.mainBox);
guiInfo.inputButton->setObjectName(...);
guiInfo.inputButton->setText(...);
guiInfo.inputButton->setCheckable(true);
guiInfo.inputButton->setChecked(false);

ui.verticalLayout_4->addWidget(guiInfo.inputButton);
```

The `ui` object is declared in the header file within the display class, like this :

```
/* GUI */
Ui::MainDisplayWindow ui;
```

and is simply obtained from the file `ui_MainDisplay.h`, included at the top and itself auto-generated out of `MainDisplay.ui`.

So yeah, we might need a bit of back and forth, because I don't even know what other infos to post.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try installing your own [`Qt` message handler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).  Then run under a debugger with a breakpoint on the handler.  The backtrace when you hit the breakpoint should (hopefully) give you some useful info regarding the location of the 'errant' code.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory: widgets cannot be created from threads other than the GUI thread (i.e., the main thread). Basically, any operation on GUI objects should be performed from the main thread. So the question is where and how you are using background threads and why you want those threads to handle GUI objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, we actually already have Qt Message Handler and it tries to produce a nice crash dialog box with infos and all, and it is *this* dialog box that brings Qt to saying that Widgets cannot be created outside of the main thread. Which, fair enough !

I know this crash dialog from the past, but here it doesn't appear at all it seems - in conformity with the error message about QWidgets.

I now see there is a case of `std::bad_alloc` which triggers our crash handling procedure, but the `bad_alloc` is really what it is. I will investigate privately or elsewhere then.